# Find a function $f(x) : f(1)=2 \land f'(x)=f(x)^2 \; \forall x$

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, functions

I cannot find a function that can be derived two times and such that $f(1)=2 \land f'(x)=f(x)^2 \; \forall x$.

Could you help?

Comment: Solve the differential equation $\frac{df}{dx}=f^2$ with the initial condition $f(1)=2$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $x$ be in a suitable interval.

Suppose $f(x)\neq 0$.
(We're not interested in what happens if  $f(x)=0$ because we're just looking for a candidate solution to the problem. Once we find it within the case $f(x)\neq 0$ we just need to verify it is indeed a solution to the problem).

Since $f'(x)=(f(x))^2$, $\dfrac{f'(x)}{(f(x))^2}=1$. Now we integrate both sides of the equation with respect to $x$. The RHS is easy enough and the LHS is a consequence of $\left(-\dfrac{1}{f}\right)'=\dfrac{f'}{f}$. So we get $-\dfrac{1}{f(x)}=x+C$, for a certain constant $C$ to be determined. From here we get $f(x)=-\dfrac{1}{x+C}$.

Since we want $f(1)=2$ we have $2=-\dfrac{1}{1+C}$. Solving for $C$ yields $C=-\dfrac {3}{2}$. 
Finally we get $f(x)=\dfrac{1}{\frac{3}{2}-x}=\dfrac{2}{3-2x}$.

Thus a possible candidate solution is $f\colon \Bbb R\setminus \{\frac{3}{2}\}\to \Bbb R, x\mapsto \dfrac{2}{3-2x}$.

Now you just need to verify that $f(1)=2$ and that $f$ is twice differentiable.

Comment: If it is not too long to explain, could you please show me the steps to solve *this* differential equation? I've never heard before about "differential equations", so I really don't know why this exercise includes that.

Comment: @collimarco For this particular case it can be done. Give me a few minutes.

Comment: @collimarco Sorry for the hold up. Lost all my work twice due to the Chrome update. It has been like this for a few weeks.